# function of text box accepting alpha letters only does not work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a function by JavaScript to accept alphabetical letters only in an input text field but the code doesn't work

```js
function isLetter(event) {
    var charCode = event.keyCode;
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lettersInput" maxlength="26" onkeypress="return isLetter(event)" class="Js-LettersEncode">
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens? What is supposed to happen? Any error messages?

Comment: your code as presented in the question works fine - check the developer tools console to find out what errors your actual code emits

Comment: note that as is, you may as well just specify the ```pattern``` attribute on the input with ```pattern="^[a-zA-Z]*$"```. It would improve readbility and avoid js

Comment: There was an extra curly bracket in my VScode which causes error , I am very sorry for inconvenience :) The code now runs thanks bros

Answer (score 1):

try with this `oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Z, ^a-z]/, '')"`

```html
<input type="text" class="typing1" name="txt1" id="t1" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Z, ^a-z]/, '')" maxlength="26" />
```